# HTML Javascript Adding a var as an input value inside a for loop

Tags: javascript, html, dom, for-loop

What I am doing is creating a table. And I am adding the values of this table using Javascript with html statements inside of a for loop. I know this may be hard to visualize so I have added a picture to show the radio buttons to the left hand side with the corresponding data on the rest of the row. I am trying to give the radio button the same value as my site id.

Here is an example of my table.

[image: table ex]

Here is my for loop:

```
   //html is the html code that will be converted from javascript to html, and the array for siteID is also declared before the for loop   
  

 //for loop to add the results to the array and also to the table
    for (var i = 0; i < results4.length; i++) {
      var object4 = results4[i];
      //the value of the site ID
      siteIDArray[i] = object4.get('SiteID');
     
      html += "<tr><td><center><br><input type='radio' onclick='alert(this.value)' 
                name='siteChosen' value='siteIDArray[i]'><center></td>";
      html += "<td><center><p>" + siteIDArray[i] + "</p></center></td>";
      ...  </tr>

 }
```

My problem is this just alerts the text `siteIDArray[i]`, and when I tried to do `value='"+siteIDArray[i]+"'` and `value="+siteIDArray[i]+"` then the table doesn't load. I feel like I am really close. Am I just missing a small thing?

---

SOLVED using Elliot de Vries's answer below!

Comment: What's exactly the error you're getting?

Comment: I don't have an error message but I can see that the table refuses to load .

Comment: But do you have any error messages in the browser console?

Comment: Where did you declare the variable `html`?

Comment: Tip: You have an unclosed `<center>` tag in the first block. It's being opened twice.

Comment: Where did you declare the array `siteIDArray`?

Comment: @Melancia I declared siteID array outside of the for loop where I also populated it with the correct data I needed. html was also declared outside of the for loop and I am using the html statements to ultimately perform an inner query.

Comment: Downvotes are anonymous. It's pointless to ask why or who.

Comment: Regarding the question, which is what matters here... I got now. I asked about the variables because they're not in the code you posted, and could be leading to errors in this case.

Comment: I just want to know how I could have improved my question better. I thought the picture and code and explanation would have been enough.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59834/discussion-between-madstermaddness-and-melanciauk).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right now the value of the "value" attribute is the string "siteIDArray[i]" and not its value.  You will want to take it outside of the quotes:

```
html += "<tr><td><center><br><input type='radio' onclick='alert(this.value)' 
                name='siteChosen' value='" + siteIDArray[i] + "'><center></td>";
```

Comment: taken from @undefined in the comments below the question

Comment: Good spot, but I don't think this would stop the table to be rendered.

Comment: Huh?  What's @undefined?

Comment: Well, every programmer knows how to concatenate the strings :)

Comment: I was having problems with my input value, as I described in my question. The table wasn't loading properly because the value was wrongly entered. Why the down vote?

Comment: If the table wasn't loading when you tried to take the array reference out of the quotes before swapping in my version of the line, I suspect it might have been just a misplaced or missing quote-- it's one of the reasons why building HTML with strings can be tricky.

Comment: I agree. It's always forgetting an equal sign or a quote mark. I knew I was close, but I was just too frustrated to see it.